# What to do when you no longer need an answer

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question to which I, in the mean time, managed to avoid having to find an answer to. Someone then went to a good bit of trouble, it seems, to provide a really thorough answer. To check if it though, would take a non-trivial amount of time/effort. I've noticed there seems to be a pressure to accept an answer on StackExchange sites.

What's the right call?

- Delete the question (not an option if it has a positive score - heads up from @Catija):

  - Pro: don't have to decide between accepting an answer without doing due diligence and going to the trouble to check it
  - Con: tough luck to anyone else who may find it useful
- Accept the answer:

  - Pro: Answerer gets the kudos
  - Con: It might be wrong
- Verify the answer

  - Please no...
- Leave it be

  - Pro: don't potentially mislead other people
  - Con: answerer may be frustrated
- Some better idea that a neophyte like me hasn't come up with yet

(Different scenario than [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298667/what-to-do-when-question-became-irrelevant-resolved-itself) or the one it links to)

Comment: The answerer will probably be more frustrated if you delete it entirely. That's way worse than not being accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Deletion is not an option, practically when it has an upvoted answer and ethically when there is no other reason than "I don't need it any more".
- Acceptance is not mandatory. If you *as the asker of the original question* found it useful and reasonable, you have the option. If it was *not helpful to you personally* you should not accept it. This judgement is yours on whatever criteria matter most *to you*, be it speed of response, depth of information, readability, accuracy, or the colour of the user's profile image (NB: the last one is very unlikely to be a good criterion).
- Upvotes for good answers are always an option and should be made whenever possible. Similarly, downvotes for bad answers. Remember the mantra: **vote early, vote often**.
- If none of the above are suitable, you can leave it. Other users are likely to vote on their own and the user who answered probably won't notice or care that there isn't a green tick, especially if it's preemptively explained why you can't verify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth remembering, it's not just about you. A good answer *could* help other users with similar problems.

There's no real pressure to select an answer (though it's nice!), especially if it's well backed up and plausible (and if you do pick one, you can change it in future). There's often not a perfect answer anyway.

Deleting it... wastes everyone's time. Comment that it's no longer an issue, but that an answer seems to be the best of the lot, select it, and nearly everyone's happy.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody's forcing you to accept an answer if you don't want to, and you certainly don't have an obligation to verify the correctness of every answer you get.

If the answer you got *seems* useful, you might still want to upvote it.  That'll show your appreciation and reward the answerer, but unlike acceptance (which can only be undone by you, or in rare cases by ♦ mods), it leaves other people the option of downvoting the answer if they disagree with it, or of providing a better answer of their own.

In fact, since you say that you managed to solve the problem on your own in the mean time, you could consider actually posting your own solution [as an answer to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).  That way, both solutions will be documented, and can be voted on by the community.

(If you like, you could also leave a comment on the other answer thanking the person who wrote it, but explaining why you're only upvoting it but not marking it as accepted.  Feel free to link to this meta thread, if you think it helps.  Note that, while SE generally discourages leaving "thanks" comments where a simple upvote and/or acceptance would do, it's perfectly fine to use comments when you actually want to communicate something other than simple gratitude.)

Comment: I don't think mods can undo a tick - tho we can delete things

Comment: I didn't solve it FYI - just decided that the advantage of having it solved for me didn't match up to the trouble involved in solving it.